# IFTTT if Feed item then Facebook Photo never run

Tags: facebook-pages, rss, if-this-then-that

I want to forward the RSS feed of a vBulletin Forum to Facebook. If the posting contains an image, it should be displayed within the facebook post.

So I used the Recipe:

```
  if [New feed item from http://example.com/feed]
then [Upload a photo from URL on myFacebookPage]
```

This recipe is active since a week. Although there have been new items, they didn't get forwarded to facebook. Next to the recipe there is the text:

> created May 05, 2015 never run

If I configure the recipe to upload them without a photo, everything works. Why does this not work for photos?

Here is an example what my feed looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>bla</title>
        <link>https://example.com/</link>
        <description>Yep</description>
        <language>de</language>
        <lastBuildDate>Wed, 13 May 2015 11:00:38 GMT</lastBuildDate>
        <generator>vBulletin</generator>
        <ttl>15</ttl>
        <image>
            <url>https://example.com/misc/rss.png</url>
            <title>Here</title>
            <link>https://example.com/</link>
        </image>
        <item>
            <title><![CDATA[Bla]]></title>
            <link>https://example.com/threads/uniqueURL</link>
            <pubDate>Mon, 11 May 2015 18:32:11 GMT</pubDate>
            <description><![CDATA[ Some text and a graphic: https://example.com/someimage.png]]></description>
            <category domain="https://example.com/cat1">cat1</category>
            <dc:creator>Someone</dc:creator>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">https://example.com/threads/uniqueURL</guid>
        </item>
        <!-- More items -->
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: That is odd. I'm not sure that we'll be able to help you here. This looks like it might be a bug on IFTTT's part. I suggest you contact their support directly. In my experience they're pretty responsive.

Answer (score 1):

The action is never carried out because the RSS feed isn't recognized as creating a new entry by IFTTT. You have't included the feed URL so this can't be fully checked. This is almost certainly a problem with the feed. Here are some steps to try:

- validate the feed's link
- use a feed santizier's RSS instead and check this triggers
- use the [Maker](http://ifttt.com/maker) channel or another trigger instead
- make sure that the vBulletin forum is not password-protected or available only when logged in, if it is see if there is an option to get emails for each photo post, and use IFTTT's email trigger instead

The [w3 feed validator](https://validator.w3.org/feed) gives warning:
**line 26, column 4: Missing atom:link with rel="self"** [instructions to fix](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/MissingAtomSelfLink.html)